# VimWiki linking to files in other directories with special characters

Tags: working-directory, plugin-vimwiki

With [vimwiki](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki) we can create a link to another file, `[[DelmeDirectory/delme.md|File]]`. I have some directories which have the form `Notes_0-0-0` and aren't recognized. i.e. pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> with the cursor over the link just takes me to an empty file.

Why does this happen? And how to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vimwiki supports markdown syntax.

You can use this:

```
[example_file](Notes_0-0-0/subfolder/example_file)
```